# Capturing signature on a webpage (via tablet screen)

Tags: javascript, php, html, json

I am trying to write a short code to capture the signature via a tablet screen on a webpage. However, I can't get the area up that captures that signature.

The code I am using, which I have borrowed from other places that do work is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>Simon's Timesheet Signature Capture Test Page</title>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/south-street/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/usr/share/javascript/jquery/jquery.signature.css" rel="stylesheet">
<style>
body > iframe { display: none; }
.kbw-signature { width: 400px; height: 200px; }
</style>
<!--[if IE]>
<script src="js/excanvas.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="/usr/share/javascript/jquery/jquery.signature.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    $('#sig').signature();
    $('#clear').click(function() {
        $('#sig').signature('clear');
    });
    $('#json').click(function() {
        alert($('#sig').signature('toJSON'));
    });
    $('#svg').click(function() {
        alert($('#sig').signature('toSVG'));
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>jQuery UI Signature Basics v18.5.2018</h1>
<p>This page demonstrates the very basics of the
    <a href="http://keith-wood.name/signature.html">jQuery UI Signature plugin</a>.
    It contains the minimum requirements for using the plugin and
    can be used as the basis for your own experimentation.</p>
<p>For more detail see the <a href="http://keith-wood.name/signatureRef.html">documentation reference</a> page.</p>
<p>Default signature:</p>
<div id="sig"></div>
<p style="clear: both;"><button id="clear">Clear</button> 
    <button id="json">To JSON</button> <button id="svg">To SVG</button></p>
</body>
</html>
```

I suspect it has something to do with the links to jquery, unless somebody can see something else glaringly obvious. (I am quite new to this)

Is anyone able to put me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Comment: Right click and view page source.  Click on the jquery.signature.js and jquery.signature.css links and see if you see any CSS or JS pop up.  If you don't, the path to the files is wrong somewhere.

Comment: Stephen - thanks for the tip. The paths have an error (so trying to find out why. Apparently it get be a permission issue.)

Comment: You shouldn't need to make it as complicated as /usr/share/etc etc.  Just make a folder in your web directory called "js" and then reference the javascript as ... <script src="js/jquery.signature.js"></script> (for example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
    <title>Simon's Timesheet Signature Capture Test Page</title>
    <link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/south-street/jquery-ui.css"
      rel="stylesheet">
<link href="../js/jquery.signature.css" rel="stylesheet">
<style>
    body > iframe {
        display: none;
    }

    .kbw-signature {
        width: 400px;
        height: 200px;
    }
</style>
<!--[if IE]>
<script src="../js/excanvas.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/jquery.signature.js"></script>
<script src="../js/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>jQuery UI Signature Basics v18.5.2018</h1>
<p>This page demonstrates the very basics of the
    <a href="http://keith-wood.name/signature.html">jQuery UI Signature plugin</a>.
It contains the minimum requirements for using the plugin and
can be used as the basis for your own experimentation.</p>
<p>For more detail see the <a href="http://keith-wood.name/signatureRef.html">documentation reference</a> page.</p>
<p>Default signature:</p>
<div id="sig"></div>
<p style="clear: both;">
    <button id="clear">Clear</button>
    <button id="json">To JSON</button>
    <button id="svg">To SVG</button>
</p>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#sig').signature();
    $('#clear').click(function () {
        $('#sig').signature('clear');
    });
    $('#json').click(function () {
        alert($('#sig').signature('toJSON'));
    });
    $('#svg').click(function () {
        alert($('#sig').signature('toSVG'));
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

There's a couple of things.  I've changed the googleapi call to https instead of http.  This helps with browsers that are tetchy with mixed content.

The code for the signature is now also at the bottom, so this should make sure the #sig div is there before the code that attaches itself to it is.  This is also helped by the document ready function.

Ignore my ../js/ for the signatures.  That's just where I put it.  See my comment above about viewing page source to see if the file is actually available.

Comment: This works on my PC, but when I goto use it on my phone or tablet, the whole page moves as opposed to the box capturing my signature. Can you head me in the direction to fix that? Key word will be fine. I imagine it is something like turning off scrolling whilst in the signature box.

Comment: I've edited the code to include the rather handy touch-punch library.  This helps jQuery-ui handle actions on touchscreens better. http://touchpunch.furf.com/